# JSON в именованный tuple / именованный tuple в JSON

Tags: python, json

Многие api работают через запросы с отправкой и приёмом json, а реляционные БД с кортежами. Подскажите как json перевести в именованный tuple и обратно. Например такой (из wiki):

```
{
   "firstName": "Иван",
   "lastName": "Иванов",
   "address": {
       "streetAddress": "Московское ш., 101, кв.101",
       "city": "Ленинград",
       "postalCode": 101101
   },
   "phoneNumbers": [
       "812 123-1234",
       "916 123-4567"
   ]
}
```

Up1. Вложенные структуры образуют имя "address.city", списки значений кортежи ("812 123-1234", "916 123-4567").

Up2. Сложность возникла при рекурсивном анализе вложенных структур. Плюс 
 по мелочи: использовать type() или isinstance() и пр.

Up3. Непосредственная сложность на примере кода:

```
json = {"firstName": "Иван", 
    "lastName": "Иванов", "address": 
    {"streetAddress": "Московское ш., 101, кв.101","city":
    "Ленинград", "postalCode": 101101}, 
    "phoneNumbers": ["812 123-1234","916 123-4567"]}

def json_to_tuple(json_):
    output = []
    for el in json_:
        output += json_to_tuple(json_[el]) if isinstance(json_[el], dict) 
                  else [(el, json_[el])]
    return output
print json_to_tuple(json)
```

Всё извлечь такой код поможет, но как сохранить имена родителей в цепочку аля "address.city"

Up4. А зачем вообще цепочка через точку? Для запросов в MongoDB и не только.

Comment: Как вы пробовали и с чем у вас возникла проблема?

Comment: Если порядок полей в кортеже имеет значение и если типов данных не слишком много, то я бы тупо написал пачку нужных присваиваний вручную

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При назначении имени с точкой именованному кортежу возникает исключение:

```
ValueError: Type names and field names can only contain alphanumeric 
    characters and underscores: 'address.city'
```

Мне помогли следующие функции, манипуляции с результатами позволят сделать необходимые именованные кортежи.

Функция для json to tuple с названиями (через точку) полей в отдельном кортеже (спасибо pocketgulag):

```
def convert_to_tuple(item):
    def json_to_tuple(json_, childe_name=''):
        output = []
        for el in json_:
            cur_name = childe_name + "." + el if childe_name != '' else el
            output += json_to_tuple(json_[el], cur_name) if 
                  isinstance(json_[el], dict) else [(cur_name, json_[el])]
        return output
    if isinstance(item, dict):
        output_dict = dict(json_to_tuple(dct))
        return tuple(output_dict.values()), tuple(output_dict.keys())
values, field_name = convert_to_tuple(dct)
```

Функция для обратной конвертации при наличии кортежа значений и кортежа названий полей с точками (также спасибо pocketgulag):

```
def convert_from_tuple(item, names=()):
    if bool(names) and isinstance(item, tuple):
        result = {}
        for n in range(0, len(names)):
            cur_result = result
            parts = names[n].split('.')
            for part in parts[:-1]:
                if part not in result:
                    cur_result[part] = {}
                cur_result = cur_result[part]
            cur_result[parts[-1]] = item[n]
        return result
print convert_from_tuple(*convert_to_tuple(dct))
```

Answer (score 1):

Такой код подойдёт?

```
import json
from collections import namedtuple

dct = json.loads('''{
   "firstName": "Иван",
   "lastName": "Иванов",
   "address": {
       "streetAddress": "Московское ш., 101, кв.101",
       "city": "Ленинград",
       "postalCode": 101101 
   },
   "phoneNumbers": [
       "812 123-1234",
       "916 123-4567"
   ]
}''')

def convert_to_tuple(item, class_name):
    if isinstance(item, dict):
        result = {}
        for k, v in item.items():
            result[k] = convert_to_tuple(v, class_name + "_" + k)
        class_obj = namedtuple(class_name, result.keys())
        return class_obj(*result.values())
    elif isinstance(item, list):
        return tuple(item)
    else:
        return item

def convert_from_tuple(item):
    if hasattr(item, "_asdict"):
        result = {}
        for k, v in item._asdict().items():
            result[k] = convert_from_tuple(v)
        return result
    else:
        return item

conv_dct = convert_to_tuple(dct, "Root")
print(conv_dct)
print(convert_from_tuple(conv_dct))
```

**Обновление**:

На основе вашего кода:

```
json = {"firstName": "Иван", 
    "lastName": "Иванов", "address": 
    {"streetAddress": "Московское ш., 101, кв.101","city":
    "Ленинград", "postalCode": 101101, "test": {"a":1, "b":2}}, 
    "phoneNumbers": ["812 123-1234","916 123-4567"]}

def json_to_tuple(json_, class_name):
    output = []
    for el in json_:
        cur_name = class_name + "." + el if class_name != '' else el
        output += json_to_tuple(json_[el], cur_name) if isinstance(json_[el], dict) else [(cur_name, json_[el])]
    return output

print json_to_tuple(json, '')
```

**Обновление 2**:

Обратное преобразование на основе вашего ответа:

```
def convert_from_tuple(tpl):
    result = {}
    dct = tpl._asdict()
    for item in dct:
        cur_result = result
        parts = item.split("0")
        for part in parts[:-1]:
            if part not in result:
                cur_result[part] = {}
            cur_result = cur_result[part]
        cur_result[parts[-1]] = dct[item]
    return result
print convert_from_tuple(convert_to_tuple(dct, "root"))
```

Comment: для json без вложений ваш код весьма хорош, спасибо

Comment: @EugeneDennis а что не так с вложениями?

Comment: если глубина вложенностиу json будет > 1, то не сработает

Comment: @EugeneDennis обновил ответ. Вообще, я подумал в начале, вам нужны namedtuple, увидев «именованный tuple»

Comment: хорошо, спасибо

Comment: @EugeneDennis забыл добавить, как обратно сделать. Обновил ответ.